# Why can't I award the bounty to my own answer

Tags: support, bounty, accepted-answer, self-answer

I [answered](https://superuser.com/a/372434/101850) my own question, why can’t I award the bounty to my answer or do something to prevent it from being half-awarded to the top-voted answer?

Comment: Please see this discussion on meta.stackoverflow, it answers this question: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/78322/why-do-i-lose-the-bounty-awarded-to-my-own-answer

Comment: You should be able to award the ounty to yourself, you won't get any rep. Are you getting any error messages or the like?

Comment: @haimg: That discussion is outdated, see the answer I will post in a moment here.

Comment: @Sathya: That is no longer possible, see the answer I will post in a moment here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the valued associate [Nick Craver](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/135201/nick-craver)'s [answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/97802/145350):

> Now that accepting an answer and awarding the bounty are 2 distinct actions - possibly from different users as well, you can no longer award the bounty to your own answer.
>
> This will take effect next build. The "+100" award button simply won't show beside your own answers.

Hence, the functionality for **awarding yourself a bounty *has been removed***.

It makes no sense to award yourself with reputation you already had; this is because the intention of a bounty is to award the user(s) that did the most effort to you in an attempt to try to help you. Even when nothing helped, you are still supposed to reward the most effort.

Back in the days, you could soak up the bounty and place it again without any loss. Then they later made it so you only get `+0` when you award it to yourself. But reputation is lost then while people did actual effort to try to get that bounty; so, they made it impossible to sink your reputation into nothing...